# AutoPostBack causes the hidden div collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have downloaded a template which is "Gentelella-Master Admin" which i used for my asp.net application. The situation is like i have a dropdownlist with autopostback enabled, when it is not active the hidden div gets collapsed wrt the dropdownlist. Can you please tell me what is wrong with my coding? Thanks for advance.

Note: When the buy product panel is not collapsed (hidden), the buy product panel shows whenever i change the dropdownlist "product" which has autopostback executed.

HERE IS INDEX.ASPX

```
 <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>New Trade Header<asp:HiddenField ID="hf1" runat="server" /></h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                        <li><a class=""><i class=""></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class=""><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="x_content">
                    <div id="demo-form2" class="form-horizontal form-label-left data-parsley-validate">
                        <div class="form-group">
                             <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Product</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddProd" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required" DataTextField="prodType" DataValueField="prID" AutoPostBack="true">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblSpecs" runat="server" class="col-md-12 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Product Specification</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddProdSpec" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required" DataTextField ="specDesc" DataValueField ="specID">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" class="col-md-12 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem" >Reference. No</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtRefNo" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" ></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblContractNo" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Contact No *</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtContractNo" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" required="required"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                             <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDeliveryDate" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Delivery Date *</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDeliveryDate" runat="server" class="date-picker form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12 required"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPurchaseContractTerms" runat="server" class="col-md-12 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Purchase Contract Terms</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddPurContractTerms" runat="server" DataTextField="purconName" DataValueField="purconID" CssClass="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" class="col-md-8 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Exhange Rate</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddExRate" runat="server" DataTextField="exRateValue" DataValueField="exRateID" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Vessel</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddVessel" runat="server" DataTextField="VesselName" DataValueField="vID" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblQuantity" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Quantity</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQuantity" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required"></asp:TextBox> 
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblValue" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Unit</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddValue" runat="server" DataTextField="metricDesc" DataValueField="metricID" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Load Port</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddLoadPort" runat="server" DataTextField="loadPortName" DataValueField="loadportID" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                                <!--remove autopostback AutoPostBack="True"-->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label11" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Disport</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddDisport" runat="server" DataTextField="disportName" DataValueField="disportID" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Buyer</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddBuyer" runat="server" DataTextField="companyName" DataValueField="comID" class="form-control col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Seller</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddSeller" runat="server" DataTextField="companyName" DataValueField="comID" class="form-control col-md-6 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required">
                                </asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align: right">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                                 <!-- modals -->
                                  <!-- Large modal -->
                            <button id="btnModalCreate" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg">Create</button>
                                <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="text-align:left">
                                      <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                          </button>
                                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Confirmation</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                          <h4>Creating Trade Header</h4>
                                          <p>Do you want to save New Trade Header Details?</p>
                                           <p>If you are not sure about the details, click Cancel</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                       <!-- <asp:Button ID="bttnNCancel" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Cancel" />-->
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                          <asp:Button ID="bttnCreate" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Save"/>
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                 <button id="bttnModEdit" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example1-modal-lg" visible ="false">Edit</button>
                                <div class="modal fade bs-example1-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="text-align:left">
                                      <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                          </button>
                                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="H1">Confirmation</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                          <h4>Editing Trade Header</h4>
                                          <p>Do you want to save changes on New Trade Header Details?</p>
                                           <p>If you are not sure about the details, click Cancel</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                      <!--<asp:Button ID="bttnNCancel1" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Cancel" />-->
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                           <asp:Button ID="bttnEdit" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Save Changes" Visible="false" />
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                               <!-- <asp:Button ID="bttnNTSave" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Save" Visible="false" />-->
                         </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end of New Trade Panel-->

        <!--buy product panel-->
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
            <div class="x_panel">
                <div class="x_title">
                    <h2>Buy Product</h2>
                    <ul class="nav navbar-right panel_toolbox">
                        <li><a class=""><i class=""></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class="collapse-link"><i class="fa fa-chevron-up"></i></a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a class=""><i class="fa fa-close"></i></a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfrfIDH" runat="server" />
                <div class="x_content">
                    <div id="Div1" class="form-horizontal form-label-left data-parsley-validate">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPurSeller" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Seller</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddPurSellers" runat="server" DataTextField="companyName" DataValueField="comID" CssClass="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPurBuyer" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Buyer</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddPurBuyer" runat="server" DataTextField="companyName" DataValueField="comID" CssClass="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPurProduct" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Product</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddPurProd" runat="server" DataTextField="prDesc" DataValueField="pID" CssClass="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required"></asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:HiddenField ID="hfProdCode" runat="server" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPurPrem" runat="server" class="col-md-10 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem ">Purchase Premium (+/-)</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPurPrem" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDate1" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Date From</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateFrom" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblDate2" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Date To</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDateTo" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblPurQty" runat="server" class="col-md-8 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Purchase Quantity</asp:Label>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="txtPurQty" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required"></asp:TextBox>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                                <asp:Label ID="lblMetric" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Unit</asp:Label>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddMetric" runat="server" DataTextField="metricDesc" DataValueField="metricID" CssClass="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required"></asp:DropDownList>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group" style="text-align: right">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                                  <button id="bttnModBuyProd" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example2-modal-lg" >Add</button>
                                <div class="modal fade bs-example2-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="text-align:left">
                                      <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                          </button>
                                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="H2">Confirmation</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                          <h4>Buy Product</h4>
                                          <p>Do you want to add this Trade?</p>
                                           <p>If you are not sure about the details, click Cancel</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                           <asp:Button ID="bttnBAdd" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Add" />
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <!--<asp:Button ID="bttnBcancel" runat="server" class="btn btn-success" Text="Cancel" />-->
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--GRIDVIEW-->
                    <asp:GridView ID="grvBuyProduct" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" class="table-responsive table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" DeleteText="Remove" />
                           <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Seller" DataField="pSeller"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Buyer " DataField="pBuyer"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="QTY" DataField="pQTY" DataFormatString="{0:#,###0.000}"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Code" DataField="pCode" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Product" DataField="pProduct" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date From" DataField="Date1" DataFormatString ="{0:dd/M/yyyy}" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Date To" DataField="Date2" DataFormatString ="{0:dd/M/yyyy}" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Total Days" DataField="TotalDays" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Pur Prem" DataField="pPurPremium" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Ave" DataField="Ave" DataFormatString="{0:#,###0.000}"/>
                             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Net Price" DataField="NetPurPrice" DataFormatString="{0:#,###0.000}"/>
                             <asp:BoundField HeaderText="USD" DataField="USD" DataFormatString="{0:#,###0.000}"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AED" DataField="AED" DataFormatString="{0:#,###0.000}"/>
                        </Columns>
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    </asp:GridView>

                    <!--table-->
                    <div class="x_title">
                        <h2>Operational Cost</h2>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblCost" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Cost</asp:Label>
                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddOperationalCosts" DataTextField="costName" DataValueField="costID" runat="server" CssClass="form-control col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 required"></asp:DropDownList>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <asp:Label ID="lblPrice" runat="server" class="col-md-7 col-sm-3 col-xs-12 tem">Price</asp:Label>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtPrice" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-3 required"></asp:TextBox>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12">
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button ID="bttnOPAdd" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Add" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!--class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action"-->
                     <asp:GridView ID="grvOperationalCost" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True"  CellPadding="4" class="table table-striped jambo_table bulk_action" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:CommandField ShowDeleteButton="True" DeleteText="Remove" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="plCostID"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Cost" DataField ="plCostName" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="USD" DataField="plCostPrice"/>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="AED" DataField ="plCostPriceAED" />
                        </Columns>
                        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    </asp:GridView> 
                     <div class="form-group" style="text-align: right">
                            <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 ">
                                  <button id="bttnModFinalSave" runat="server" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example3-modal-lg" visible="false">Save</button>
                                <div class="modal fade bs-example3-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
                                     <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" style="text-align:left">
                                      <div class="modal-content">
                                        <div class="modal-header">
                                          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                                          </button>
                                          <h4 class="modal-title" id="H3">Confirmation</h4>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                          <h4>Saving New Trade Details</h4>
                                          <p>Do you want to add this Trade?</p>
                                           <p>If you are not sure about the details, click Cancel</p>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                                           <asp:Button ID="bttnFinalSave" runat="server" class="btn btn-primary" Text="Save" />
                                        </div>
                                      </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    <!-- end of Buy Product Panel-->
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to set the visibility of the div again after postback.

```
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "showDiv", "document.getElementById('myDiv').style.display = 'block';", true);
        }
```